# Order Relations (ManyToMany) without duplicating records django

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql

For days I've been trying to sort a series of queries by passing as parameter objects.order_by ("relation").distinct() of type "ManyToMany" but always duplicates the query "x" the number of relations, the last being the desired.

```
class Person(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  groups = models.ManyToManyField('Group', through='GroupMember', related_name='people')

  class Meta:
      ordering = ['name']

  def __unicode__(self):
      return self.name

class Group(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

  class Meta:
      ordering = ['name']

  def __unicode__(self):
      return self.name

class GroupMember(models.Model):
  person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='membership')
  group = models.ForeignKey(Group, related_name='membership')
  type = models.CharField(max_length=100)

  def __unicode__(self):
      return "%s is in group %s (as %s)" % (self.person, self.group, self.type)

# Create three people:
self.joe = Person.objects.create(name='Joe')

# And three groups:
self.jocks = Group.objects.create(name='Jocks')
self.nerds = Group.objects.create(name='Nerds')

GroupMember.objects.create(person=self.joe, group=self.jocks, type="admin")
GroupMember.objects.create(person=self.joe, group=self.nerds, type="owner")
GroupMember.objects.create(person=self.joe, group=self.nerds, type="member")

# Not work, recieve multiple queries duplicates.
# (alphabetical order)
# We need order_by GroupMember().type. "admin, member, owner,... "
Person.objects.all()\
             .order_by("membership__type")\
             .distinct("id")
```

Note that although adding "distinct ()" is duplicating the values of the query, my question is what is the reason and how to solve it. The database that I am using PostgreSQL. Thank you.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related and check out `vales_list()`

Comment: How do you want it to order Person with multiple memberships? Think about this. It is not logically possible,  thus you can't get rid of duplicates

Comment: @AlexandrTatarinov You're right, clearly an example, I just eliminated it. In the same way, we try to order by any other field the external relationship continues to pass the same problem.

Comment: I am not sure I understand you fully. With any relationship where there can be multiple rows on the right table in join,  the is no way to order left table by column in right table without duplicates. I.e. we have person 1 which belongs to groups Anonymous and Forbidden.  And person 2 which belongs to group Basic.  How would you order that person's by group name?

Comment: For your updated answer,  if the person is admin in one group and owner of another,  how can you determine the order of this person among others by membership type without duplicating?